How to use array data from API request to make multiplechoice question?
Currently I’m trying to build Telegram-bot from the constructor. I do API request to one service using Action “External Request”, I get data like this:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "entities_id": 0,
        "is_recursive": 0,
        "name": "Company 1",
        "comment": "",
        "ldap_field": null,
        "ldap_value": null,
        "ldap_group_dn": null,
        "date_mod": "2024-01-31 16:31:44",
        "groups_id": 0,
        "completename": "Company 1",
        "level": 1,
        "ancestors_cache": "[]",
        "sons_cache": null,
        "is_requester": 1,
        "is_watcher": 1,
        "is_assign": 1,
        "is_task": 1,
        "is_notify": 1,
        "is_itemgroup": 1,
        "is_usergroup": 1,
        "is_manager": 1,
        "date_creation": "2024-01-31 16:31:44"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "entities_id": 0,
        "is_recursive": 0,
        "name": "Company 2",
        "comment": "",
        "ldap_field": null,
        "ldap_value": null,
        "ldap_group_dn": null,
        "date_mod": "2024-02-07 17:48:06",
        "groups_id": 1,
        "completename": "Company 1 > Company 2",
        "level": 2,
        "ancestors_cache": "{\"1\":1}",
        "sons_cache": null,
        "is_requester": 1,
        "is_watcher": 1,
        "is_assign": 1,
        "is_task": 1,
        "is_notify": 1,
        "is_itemgroup": 1,
        "is_usergroup": 1,
        "is_manager": 1,
        "date_creation": "2024-02-07 17:48:06"
    },
    {
...
    }
]

Then I need to create a question, where the choices are the name’s attributes’ values from those data. A question with multiple choices. And I need to create it dynamically. I mean, if I have 79 entities, then there’ll be 79 choices (values of name’s attributes), if I have 50, then there’ll be 50.
What I do now is trying to save these array data into custom user field “group_array” in Response Mapping. custom user field “group_array” is a user field that I’ve created in Settings. It seems like I can use it in Response Mapping:
$ →group_array
But when I want to display the value of the variable, I mean just “Send Message” Action, I use {}, but there’s no such variable. And I don’t understand why…
Here are the screenshots:



